# How to check whether iphone control center is present or not in swift 2.2?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I want to check whether control center is present in UIviewController.swift file or not,
how to do it?
please help me.

Comment: Just wondering why is it important to check specifically for control center?

Answer (score 2):

You can not do that. check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034907/check-if-control-center-is-used) for reference

If they are active you can only check whether your app has backgrounder or foregrounded